# Word for one too many items

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Perhaps this word doesn't exist.  I'm looking for the word to describe the last final thing you want to put in a container but it won't fit.  There is always one of those.  You have ten items but always only nine will fit into the container you have.  Often occurs with a toolbox which has one too many tools to go into it.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. You asking for a "word for one too many items" appears to be asking for a noun, while you then asking for a "word to describe the last thing you want to put in a container but won't fit" appears to be asking for an adjective. Then there's the fact that whether it's an adjective or a noun you seek, "one too many" and "one more than will fit" are two different definitions, so you have to clarify which of those you want.

Comment: The straw that broke the camel’s back; a faggot above a load.

Comment: "Leftover" might work. It's usually used for uneaten prepared food like cold cuts off a joint of meat but it could describe items like the ones you mention. You might get a situation like "I took out the drill so that I could get all the spanners and screwdrivers into the box, now the drill is the only leftover item."

Comment: Similar to Xanne's options: the last drop (that makes the cup run over)

Comment: If it's a toolbox, I'd say "the odd one out" — because not only is it surplus, but it also must not belong to that set. Still thinking about whether there's a more general term.

Comment: @Xanne "straw that broke the camel's back" would apply if you actually did try to put the extra one in, and it shattered as a result.

Comment: One could continue the sequence penultimate (one before last), ultimate (last) by word smithing: 'post-ultimate'.   Alternatively the phrase "a day late and a dollar short" might be the sentiment.  Or "fifth wheel".  But none of these quite seem to fit.

Answer (score 1):

How about *excess*?  The OED gives as one example of its usage:

> excess luggage: luggage over the weight for which a passenger is allowed free carriage.

The meanings are broader than what you are looking for but I think the meaning you want is one of the meanings of *excess*.

Comment: Excess works for "too many items" but it's not specific enough for "one too many".

Answer (score 0):

In my family, although I'm not sure when it first originated, we've always used the term square peg. Such as:

> Figures, get the suitcase basically done and last thing ended up being a square peg.

It just comes from the old thing of a square peg trying to fit into a round hole in the children's block game. Can't force it through the circle slot no matter how much you want it to fit in. I am aware this is a pretty silly way of using the old idiom loosely, but for some reason it always really just felt like the perfect thing to say ever since I first heard my Grandfather use it when I was a child.

Comment: Hello, Brandon. Nice idea, nice anecdote ... but not an established usage.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a maths style phrase like ...

> My toolbox holds N items, but I always seem to have “N + 1” items.

Pronounce like “n plus one”.

> ... the (N + 1)th item ends up in my back pocket.

Pronounce like “n plus oneth item”

Answer (score 0):

I believe [superfluous](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/superfluous) would work quite well, as in:

> After my toolbox is full, I never quite know what to do with the superfluous hammer.

EDIT: Perhaps poetically, such an item might be referred to as "[vestigial](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/vestigial)" in the sense of "pertaining to a vestige or remnant."

Comment: This implies that an object is unneeded or not useful rather than excessive or ample.

Comment: In my example, the hammer is certainly not needed nor useful for filling the toolbox. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little too formal, but *[supernumerary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supernumerary)* fits the bill:

> Something which is beyond the prescribed or standard amount or number.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe *[remnant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remnant)*

> a usually small part, member, or trace remaining

or *[remainder](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remainder#synonyms)*

> a: a remaining group, part, or trace
> b: (1) the number left after a subtraction (2): the final undivided part after division that is less
> or of lower degree than the divisor

Comment: A remnant might be an off-cut due to aesthetics or function - it may well fit if stuffed into the container that holds the rest.

Answer (score -1):

Postultimate! Post-ultimate?

> The postultimate Cheeto bulged from the top of the Tupperware container.

Comment: Hi, Dellevue. We're not in the business of suggesting neologisms. Please cite established uses. Please take time to complete the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and learn more about our mission. :)